# Upper bound for $\sup_{W_d(Q, P) \le \epsilon} Q(A)$, where $W_d$ is the Wasserstein metric

Tags: measure-concentration, geometric-probability, probability-distributions

Let $X=(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $W_d$ denote the Wasserstein metric induced by this metric, on the space of probability distributions on $X$. Let $\epsilon \ge 0$,  $A$ be a Borel subset of $X$, and consider the quantity
$$I := \sup_{W_d(Q, P) \le \epsilon} Q(A).
$$

I'm able to establish the following lower bound: $I \ge P([A]_\epsilon)$, where
$$[A]_\epsilon := \{x \in X | d(x, A) \le \epsilon\}
$$
is the $\epsilon$-blowup of $A$ and $d(x, A) := \inf\{d(x, y) | y \in A\}$ is the distance of $x$ from $A$.

## Question

What is a reasonable upper bound for $I$ in terms of $A$ and $\epsilon$ ?

Comment: I do not that some reasonable upper bounds can be found. Just consider the case of countable dense set $A$. Then for arbitrarily near Dirac measures $P,Q$ we can have $P(A)=0$ and $Q(A)=1$.

Comment: @TarasBanakh For small $\epsilon < 1$, maybe something like $I \le P([A]_{\sqrt{\epsilon}}) + \sqrt{\epsilon}$ ? Since The Levy-Prokhorov metric is upper bounded by the the square root of the Wasserstein.

Comment: @NateEldredge Are you sure about the example? It seems like $Q_n = \frac{1}{n} P + \frac{n-1}{n} \delta_{-1/n^2}$ (for $n$ large enough) is a sequence which shows $I = 1$.

Comment: @Steve: You're right.  Sorry.